# How to put a value of variable into function which reads a name of variable as value of variable?

Tags: r

I got this:

```
if(require(shiny)==F){
  install.packages(shiny)
}
library(shiny)

if(require(ggplot2)==F){
  install.packages(ggplot2)
}
library(ggplo2)
```

I want to rewrite this code to make it more inteligent. I want to establish a variable at the begening which will be a vector of libaries I want to load and then I want the code which will use all this elements of the vector. I tried to do this by this:

```
libraryName <- c("shiny","ggplot2")    
if(require(libraryName)==F){
      install.packages(libraryName)
    }
    library(libraryName)
```

but library(libraryName) read is no like library(shiny) and library(ggplot2) but like library(libraryName) :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this what you want?

```
libraryName <- c("shiny", "ggplot2")   
for (p in libraryName) 
    library(p, character.only = TRUE)
```

Comment: yes, thank you very much. So the "character.only" clause is a key to victory here.